# Custom adapter checkbox listener nullpointer exception

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I am trying to implement a checkbox listener in a custom adapter I have made for my listview.

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

private Activity activity;
private List<String> items;
private LayoutInflater inflater = null;

public CustomAdapter(Activity a, int resource, List<String> i) {
    super(a, resource, i);
    activity = a;
    items = i;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) a.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi = convertView;

    if (vi == null) {
        vi = inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, parent, false);
    }

    //View itemName = (CheckedTextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
//  View checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text1);

   // TextView itemName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
    CheckedTextView checkbox = (CheckedTextView) convertView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
    Log.d("test", "testing");
    ((CheckedTextView) (checkbox)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view){
            CheckBox c = (CheckBox) view;
            Log.d("Test", "testing2");
        }
    });

    return vi;

}
```

}

Made some changes to the code and now I am receiving an NPE on the line I am defining my checkedtextview.

12-05 15:09:02.241: E/AndroidRuntime(29134): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-05 15:09:02.241: E/AndroidRuntime(29134):    at com.example.mercbisandroid.CustomAdapter.getView(CustomAdapter.java:41)
12-05 15:09:02.241: E/AndroidRuntime(29134):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2263)

Comment: checkbox is already Checkbox type ..why are you again typecasting??

Comment: Why are your TextView itemName and checkbox having same id --R.id.text1

Comment: are you using same id for TextView and Checkbox? R.id.text1?

Comment: I would say you're also getting a ClassCastException on the second call to findViewById(), as it's using the same resource id as the line above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the source for android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice (which is what you are inflating):

```
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
    android:paddingLeft="6dip"
    android:paddingRight="6dip"
/>
```

This line below then results in null (hence your subsequent NPE when you try to attach a listener) because there is nothing with that id in the above layout:

```
CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
```

The correct id to use is this:

```
CheckedTextView checked_tv = (CheckedTextView) convertView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
```

Note that you cannot cast a CheckedTextView to a CheckBox. So either work with the CheckedTextView you get from this layout or you can inflate your own layout containing a CheckBox instead if you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

You're `CheckBox` is not a `CheckBox`, but a `TextView` because you're calling `findViewById` using the same resource ID as used for itemName.

Answer (score 0):

R.id.text1 is either a TextView or CheckBox. I mean it in the same order: If it is a TextView, it is not a CheckBox.

```
TextView itemName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
```

Comment: This doesn't make any sense - if your layout defines an ID of `text1` for a given view type then it can't be both types of views.

Comment: Yes of course this is the problem. However, in practice, R.id.text1 could be a CheckBox and these two statements would be valid. Finally, the fact that he is getting a NPE most probably means that R.id.text1 is not even in the layout.

Comment: @LarrySchiefer The problem isn't with the id at all. OP checks whether `vi` is `null` and inflates a view. But, instead of using `vi` to `findViewById`, s/he uses `convertView`, which may as well be null at this point. Duplicate ids will cause problems, but that isn't the issue right now.